# What's the name of the SQL SP that locates a text string?

Tags: sql-server

I am very embarrassed but I cannot remember the name of the MS SQL Server SP that searches your DB for a specified text string and returns all the table names, functions, stored procedures etc that contain that string.  And I can't look it up in the help, because in order to get help on it, you need to know its name!  It was something like `sp_findtext`.

What is it called?

Come on, fastest fingers gets answer credit!  :)

Comment: There is such an SP? Damn, I wrote such a thing myself because I thought there wasn't anything like that...

Comment: Ah, turns out there isn't - I thought there was but someone else in my last job had written it... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=32319

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_FindText @text varchar(8000), @findtype varchar(1)='P' AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF @findtype='P' SELECT DISTINCT Len(SubString(text,1, PatIndex('%' + @text + '%', text)))-Len(Replace(SubString(text,1, PatIndex('%' + @text + '%', text)),char(13),''))+1 AS Line,
--PatIndex('%' + @text + '%', text) AS Position,
OBJECT_NAME(id) AS ProcName
FROM syscomments
WHERE text like '%' + @text + '%'
ORDER BY ProcName, Line

IF @findtype='C' EXEC('SELECT TABLE_NAME + ''.'' + COLUMN_NAME AS TableColumn FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''%' + @text + '%'' ORDER BY TableColumn')

IF @findtype='T' EXEC('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%' + @text + '%'' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME')
GO
```

It not only searches procedure and view definition text, it will also find tables, views, and column names:

```
EXEC sp_FindText 'myTable' --or-- EXEC sp_FindText 'myTable', 'P' --finds procedures/views containing 'myTable' in their definition/code
EXEC sp_FindText 'myTable', 'T' --finds tables/views containing 'myTable' in their name
EXEC sp_FindText 'myCol', 'C' --finds columns containing 'myCol' in their name
```

Comment: This is the best one, most versatile.  Thanks!

Comment: But wrong... syscomments only stores nvarchar(4000) so this fails if the search string of 4 letters starts at 3999 so this is unreliable

Answer (score 2):

I found a custom SP (FindTextInDatabase) that does exactly that:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110817001556/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ram/archive/2007/05/22/112672.aspx)

Don't know if there's a ready-made procedure also. If there is one, I can't find it either.

Answer (score 0):

Have a quick check on the results of these:

```
select * from sysobjects where [name] like 'sp_%' order by 1
select * from master..sysobjects where [name] like 'sp_%' order by 1
```

You find what is it for you.

Cheers!

Comment: You know that "ORDER BY 1" is completely useless, don't you?

Comment: How is it useless?  It orders by the first output column.

Comment: It would would be completely useless if you don't know what it is.